# npm install error 1, trouble shooting failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've tried all the fixes I can find, but cannot seem to get npm to function. Hoping someone may have additional insight around this error:

Fixes I have tried:

- Adding %AppData%\npm to PATH
- Complete reinstall, including node, and all PATH
- Changing the prefix from -g to --global
- Changing the NPM Version
- Install prisma and reinstalling prisma

npm version: 8.11.0
node version: v16.16.0
Using VS Code

```js
PS C:\Users\txxxx\SaaStime> npm install
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\txxxx\SaaStime
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prisma generate
npm ERR! 'prisma' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
```

This is the Error I get in the log:

```
61 timing command:install Completed in 82ms
62 verbose stack Error: command failed
62 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\lib\index.js:63:27)
62 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
62 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
62 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(node:internal/child_process:302:5)
63 verbose pkgid nextacular@1.2.0-Beta
64 verbose cwd C:\Users\toril\SaaStime
65 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22000
66 verbose node v16.16.0
67 verbose npm  v8.11.0
68 error code 1
69 error path C:\Users\toril\SaaStime
70 error command failed
71 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prisma generate
72 error 'prisma' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
72 error operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: What is prisma?

Comment: Have you [followed the step-by-step instructions](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/quickstart) on getting Prisma up-and-running? You may not be able to use it in a windows command-line like that.

Comment: It seems you should install the `prisma` globally. Try it `npm i -g prisma` then retry

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of no avail, I finally figured it out.

If you are using `npm install` on windows it will throw errors.

My first fix to this was `yarn` which allowed me to run just fine.

Then, I decided to do a dual-boot ubuntu and have had zero issues with npm or any node packages.